# Detecting touch event coordinates on a View

Tags: android, user-interface

I have an ImageView on which i want to know the coordinates of the touch event with respect to that ImageView. I tried getX() and getY() methods of MotionEvent, donesn't seem to work. Also i want to know if the y coordinate value is a negative or positive value, because by convention we are measuring from top to bottom, so it should be negative. Plz help.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work"?  Precision is important when coding.

Comment: i don't know what value(-ve or +ve) getY() returns and with respect to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The origin (0,0) is top left.  getX() and getY() return x and y relative to the View, getRawX() and getRawY() return x and y relative to the screen.

Comment: does the getY() returns positive y coordinate or negative?

Comment: +ve WRT top left - you could always test it ;)  But note, you can click outside the view!

Comment: but i have put the listener on that view only, and that view has no any children.